# How to specify agent / formula to retrieve documents by criteria

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

The form contains "searchInputField" and simple button for it. Below the button, there is a view.

How can i specify SELECT formula in VIEW according to searchInputCriteria? I want to refresh VIEW when button is clicked after setting "searchInputField". It should be like simple custom search.

On button click i have done:

```
@SetEnvironment("criteria", "searchInputField");
@Command([RunAgent];"searchAgent");
@Command([ViewRefreshFields]);
```

My agent does:

```
SELECT @Like(propertyA, @Environment("criteria"));
```

But it doesn't do anything. I'm new to Lotus Notes. Please, give me some guidelines

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that a homework or so? It looks so similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/29747945/2065611...

Comment: I can't think of a good solution with just formula. You'd get it to run on a locale database/view but that is nothing what you would offer for production. Use a user specific folder and LotusScript with notesDatabase.Search() and notesDocumentCollection.PutAllInFolder() instead.

Comment: Views have a fixed selection formula. You need Designer permission to change it. Standard viiews are shared resources on the server, and are not intended to be dynamically modified on a per-user basis. But similar to @KnutHerrmann's suggestion, you could use LotusScript of Java code to create or modify a private view, which is always user-specific.

Comment: Some additional information may help us to help you solve your real problem. I'm not convinced you need to do any of this.  Are you aware that Lotus Notes' built-in search feature includes the ability to create customized search forms? Using that feature, there's no reason why you would have to be running an agent, and the search criteria entered by the user on the form would be used to select the documents displayed in the result set. Can you tell us why this isn't good enough for you?

Comment: Here's a link to a description of the feature.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CUSTOMIZING_SEARCH_FORMS_7304.html

Comment: @KnutHerrmann thanks, that's one of feasible solutions;

Comment: @RichardSchwartz it's maybe me, not a lotus notes because of lack of time to read documentation. As you said, im trying to archieve what is already built-in. But if it possible to make a custom implementation, i prefer to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

You could use this script inside your button but it won't work in a dynamic, real-time way:

```
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim uiw As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim formula As String
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim view As NotesView       
Set db=session.CurrentDatabase
Set uidoc=uiw.CurrentDocument
Set doc=uidoc.Document
Set view=db.GetView("MyEmbeddView")     
formula$={SELECT  @Like(criteria;  "} & doc.searchInputField(0) & {")}
view.SelectionFormula=formula
```

The only way to see the changes in a reliable way is to close and reopen the database. It's also a very expensive way of working in terms of performance.
I advise you not to use this way of working to change view selections 'on the fly'. It can be useful to change views that stay static for a while after the change. For example you could write an agent that changes the selection formulas on a periodic basis (e.g., monthly or daily at a non-peak time or during a maintenance window).

In your case I advise using single category views or to populate a folder on the fly.
Single category views will work much faster than dynamically calculating the `DocumentCollection` used to populate a folder.